# IDA* with 15-puzzle, help needed

Tags: artificial-intelligence, programming-languages, a-star

I have to make a visualisation of the **IDA***(iterative deepening A star) **algorithm** when it is running a 15-puzzle problem. Exactly, I need to visualize the **tree** and the **puzzle**.

IDA* algorithm is similar to the A* algorithm. [link 1](http://www.inf.uos.de/papers_html/ai_94/node2.html#SECTION00020000000000000000) [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA*) [3](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/AI-Programming/IDA-Star.html)

There are 3 things I need to implement:

1)The IDA* code.

2)After that, the IDA* connected with the problem(15-puzzle).

3)And, after that, I need to visualize the tree of the algorithm.

**But I believe that someone before must have implemented the code for the IDA* running the 15-puzzle problem. I need your help to find this source code so that I would not spent 2 months writing code that has been written by someone else before, so that I would have time to focus on the visualization.**

15-puzzle [link 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle) , [link 2](http://www.javaonthebrain.com/java/puzz15/)

I know some C,C++ and C#.

I need a simple source code, that I would comprehend, in which you input a table as a puzzle and it gives you back as a table with the solved puzzle.

Secondly, what programming language from the 3 above do you suggest me to use for the visualization?

I have found some implementations:

[IDA* in LISP](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~russell/code/search/algorithms/ida.lisp)

[A* in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990168/a-star-algorithm), I need IDA*

[IDA* in java](http://aima-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/aima-core/src/main/java/aima/core/search/uninformed/IterativeDeepeningSearch.java)

[IDA* in pheudocode link1](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/AI-Programming/IDA-Star.html) [link2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA*) [link3](http://www.inf.uos.de/papers_html/ai_94/node2.html#SECTION00020000000000000000)

[IDA* in C](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid5C2AB98F6AC72C8BDBB25312E22FBDF85AC7A3CF.aspx)

[IDA* with 15-puzzle](http://www.brian-borowski.com/Software/Puzzle/)

[15-puzzle solved in an applet](http://www.javaonthebrain.com/java/puzz15/puzz.java)

A* and IDA* that solves Sliding puzzle (This one uses templates that aren't defined)

Comment: If this is a core component of your research, asking this question is foolish - you'll struggle to assign credit, and you aren't going to learn how to do this yourself. If it isn't, consider referencing someone else's work if you don't have time to do the work yourself

Comment: @george mano : see this link(it is in java however) - http://www.brian-borowski.com/Software/Puzzle/ . Scroll down to the middle of the page. you will find the source code there.

Comment: IDA* is fairly simple to implement. Furthermore, you shouldn't try to copy-paste an implementation for your work, without understanding the code. I strongly suggest you go over the links you yourself linked, and understand the simplicity of the algorithm. Then, implement it yourself. Eventually, this will save you a lot of time when you will plug-in your visualizations.

Answer (score 0):

IDA* takes approximately ten minutes to implement.  Your heuristic function is trivial, I guess you at least manage to implement manhattan distance (there are better heuristics, but this'll do).

Then you simply implement A* and then add the cut-off limit criteria.  The Wikipedia article you link to even has an implementation in Python you simply can translate.